# pmap memory listing of a process having more than one dynamic shared library

Tags: c++, c, memory, pmap

I have an executable which loads 2 shared library using dl_open

each of the shared library allocates memory of 1MB every 2minutes and 3 minutes respectively.

using pmap how can i know how memory was allocated by each of these shared libs..

Say after 5 minutes if i use pmap....will i be able to locate the memory allocated  by each shared libs as 2MB and 1MB or pmap just shows overall memory allocation so far as 3MB?

Am using SuSE 10, i could only see pmap showing overall memory allocation as 3MB...
are there any flags or suggestions to get to know the details per shared libary

regards
ragha

Comment: No, there is no difference between pieces of memory allocated by this or that piece of code. They all draw from a common pool. And `pmap` doesn't know about allocated memory anyway. It only tracks mapped memory.